# Center navigation bar content and still keep responsivness in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for this. I did create a navbar, and it did collapse when the google chrome window was shrinked down, ad it should. But when I added some css to center the content in the navbar, it does no longer "collapse" when the window is shrinked, and the navbar `<li>` completly disappears. Why is that? here is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="bar">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="barbar">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#testen">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="testen">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="home.html" id="home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="book.html" id="bone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Booking</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="about.html" id="hact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html" id="bthree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" id="logg><a href="logga.html">Sign in</a></button>
            </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

Here is the css:

```
#barbar{
width: 960px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

When I add this css above to the css file, its then when the "collapsing" of the navbar stops. How can I center the navbar content and still keep the "collapsing" of the navbar when shrinking the google chrome window?

Comment: Put that in a min-width where your menu collapses. You would write a media query

Comment: Try this - http://www.bootply.com/render/pEJJEFWCPy and http://www.bootply.com/pEJJEFWCPy

Comment: @MaryMelody So you did no changes to the html code, just in css? (media query, as Christina also suggested?)

Comment: Yeah, as suggested by Christina

Comment: Ok, thanks! @MaryMelody. answer my question with what you wrote in the comments, so i can upvote&accept answer if you want

Comment: @Christina Thank you! The links in your bio was also very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @MaryMelody is a rockstar!

Comment: @Christina that was your idea originally so you should create the answer :)

Comment: You made the Bootply so go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it like this: (As suggested by [@Christina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414641/center-navigation-bar-content-and-still-keep-responsivness-in-bootstrap#comment41477137_26414641))

**Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/pEJJEFWCPy)**

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #barbar {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 980px;
   }
}
```